# Remove mobile Safari touchcancel

Tags: jquery, touch, mobile-safari

How do you remove mobile safari touchcancel? I have a li and after an event it adds a touchcancel. I was wondering if somebody might know how to remove that as well as why it occurs possibly.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove the event, but you can bind to the event and then preventDefault on it so nothing happens.

using jQuery

```
  $(document).on('touchcancel', function(event){event.preventDefault()})
```